# how to put link in the kable() R

Tags: r, api, markdown

How can you put link inside the kable()? For example,

`{r}
library(knitr)
x <- cars$speed
hist(x)
cars$website[1:10] <- [Link](some url)
kable(cars)`

Why is that link not working when I knit this? This is html format.

Comment: what happens when you knit?  If you run that code chunk as it's written, I bet you'd have an R error first

Comment: if i remove that `cars$website[1:10] <- [Link](some url)`, everything works. I just wrote the code section, not including any title, output, or packages

Comment: but what do you mean by "not working"?  an R error?  a compilation error?  or just a non-linky bit of text in your kable?

Comment: I want that 'Link' showing on the kable() part so that I can click and go to that website! I got error in parse(text = x, blahblahbalh)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in quotes:

```
x <- cars
x$website <- "[link](http://stackoverflow.com)"
library(knitr)
kable(x)
```

or however you'd like to structure the links as a character vector.  The key here is that it's evaluating the R code first before turning it into html.

Or better yet, here's how you could combine a vector of different urls...

```
library(knitr)
x <- cars[1:3,]
urls <- c("stackoverflow.com", "stats.stackexchange.com", "homebrew.stackexchange.com")
linkID <- c("link1", "link2", "link3")
x$website <- paste0("[", linkID, "](http://", urls, ")")
kable(x)
```